# Remove extra pipes from middle of line in notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, pipe, notepad++

I have a pipe delimeted txt file which has a free text column in the middle, and sometimes that free text contains a pipe, which throws of the entire file when I import it into Excel.

I know that each line should have 4 pipes, so I want to identify lines with more than 4 pipes and replace the 3rd one with a space.

Location|Date|Comment|System|

NYC|10.10.2019|correct|windows|

**Los Angeles|10.10.2019|error|5|windows|**

Chicago|10.10.2019|error 3|Linux|

I already figured out how to identify a line with more than 4 pipes:

`^([^|\r\n]*\|){5}`

I have not been able to find how to replace the 3rd pipe.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is: capture the `N-1` number of non-pipes followed with a pipe and the following 0 or more non-pipes into Group 1, then match the Nth pipe, and then capture `M-N` amount of non-pipe chars followed with a pipe (`N` is the pipe to remove occurrence and `M` is how many pipes there should be on a line).

You may use

**Find What**: `^((?:[^|\r\n]*\|){2}[^|\r\n]*)\|((?:[^|\r\n]*\|){2})`
**Replace With**: `$1 $2`

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `((?:[^|\r\n]*\|){2}[^|\r\n]*)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): two repetitions of 0+ chars other than pipe, LF and CR followed with a pipe and then 0+ chars other than pipe, LF and CR
- `\|` - the third `|`
- `((?:[^|\r\n]*\|){2})` - Capturing group 2 (`$2`): two repetitions of 0+ chars other than pipe, LF and CR followed with a pipe.

Test and settings:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the logic? I also have other files where I need to replace the 20th pipe in a line with 24 pipes? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Long_Eddy Added on top of the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Solved alot of my problems.Thanks

Comment: Do you if it possible to remove more than 1 pipe leaving the the text in between? I ran the file and caught some lines that had more than 1 pipe in the free text column. For Example: Los Angeles|10.10.2019|error|5|unknow|windows|. the final result should be Los Angeles|10.10.2019|error 5 unknow|windows|

Comment: @Long_Eddy Yes, possible, but can't you just click *Replace All* several times? It seems easiest.